# How to toggle a slide menu from the left with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

For a mobile page to be used on iPhones etc. I am trying to create a menu which will slide in from the left and push the current content out to the right much like in phone apps. With a touch anywhere in the displayed menu (other than a link) the menu should disappear again and the page should be displayed again as before.

I use the http://aozora.github.io/bootplus/index.html Bootplus CSS to have a decent look of the site and make it also responsive.

I was able to get the slide in effect going nicely using the following jQuery code:

```
$('#leftmenu').hide();
$('#button').on('click',function(){
  $('#content').css({'position':'fixed'}).animate({"left":"85%"});
  $('#leftmenu').css({'position':'fixed', 'width':'85%'});
  $('#leftmenu').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

For the menu, I have the following html.

```
<div id="leftmenu" class="container" style="width: 85%; left:0%; height: 100%; background-color:silver">
   <br />
   <p><h3>Quick links</h3></p>
   <p><h4><a href="">Home</a></h4></p>
   <p><h4><a href="">Page 1</a></h4></p>
   <p><h4><a href="">Page 2</a></h4></p>
</div>
<div class="navbar .navbar-inverse" style="background-color:silver; vertical-align:middle">
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <i id="button" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

But when I hide the menu with the code below, the page no longer shows centered in the middle, but aligned to the left with no left margin anymore.

```
$('#leftmenu').on('click',function(){
  $('#content').css({'position':'absolute'}).animate({"left":"0%"});
  $('#leftmenu').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I understand that I do that with the css code, but I struggle to make it work with a toggle mechanism with which I can get back to the previous css settings without having to redefine all from scratch.

Another issue I face is that whenever I touch the menu on the left, I need to touch twice to make it disappear. To show the menu, it works with a single touch on the Menu button, yet the hiding requires two touches.

Thanks a million for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The default positioning is `static`, so the inline `left` rule is ignored. You're trying to set it back to `absolute`, and then the `margin-left` doesn't apply (I'm not sure what's your DOM structure there). Why are you using so much inline CSS?
A better approach I suggest is to set css classes for a displayed and non-displayed states of the menu.

CSS:

```
.leftmenu{
  // whatever base rules you have
  // css3 animations set here - better performance than JS.
}
.content{
  // whatever base rules you have
  // css3 animations set here - better performance than JS.
}
.leftmenu-displayed{
  position: fixed;
  width: 85%;
}
.content-displayed{
  position: fixed;
  left: 85%;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.leftmenu').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('leftmenu-displayed');
  $('.content').toggleClass('content-displayed');
});
```

Also, avoid using so many ID's. They have no advantage over classes here.